# Problems in Markup.js accessing variable from the root when inside a loop

Tags: javascript, templates, markup

I'm using **Markup.JS** ( https://github.com/adammark/Markup.js ), and it works well for the most of it. The problem I'm having, is accessing a variable from the parent loop. Here is the object that gets passed to it:

[image]

The template code is:

```
This works here: {{perms.link_modify}}

{{links_loop}}
<tr>
    <td><a href="{{detailed_url}}" target="_blank">{{Title}}</a></td>
    <td>{{if URL}}
            <a href="{{URL}}" target="_blank">{{URL}}</a>
        {{else}}
            n/a
        {{/if}}</td>
    <td>
        {{if isValidated}}
            <!-- doesn't have a value here -->
            foo: {{perms.link_modify}}
        {{else}}
            <!-- not relevent to question -->
        {{/if}}
    </td>
</tr>
{{/links_loop}}
```

When run, this part:

```
            foo: {{perms.link_modify}}
```

Comes up as ??? (non-recognised variable). The problem seems to be that it's not realising its meant to be coming from the root (not inside the loop itself). Is there a way to tell it to go up one level when looking? (hopefully that makes sense!)

**FWIW**, I'm aware I can just copy the value of "perms" into the loop values, but this means repeating the same data over and over, and seems a bit of a messy hack (especially if there are 100's of items in the loop, as `perms` would need to be repeated in every one)

**UPDATE:** I just found this post: https://github.com/adammark/Markup.js/pull/51/files?diff=split&short_path=04c6e90

I'm on version 1.5.21, so I'm trying to see how to implement it (as it's not released)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so while it seems this isn't possible with the current release (v1.5.21), it is possible with this hack:

https://github.com/adammark/Markup.js/pull/51/files?diff=split&short_path=04c6e90

I've applied this fix, and it works well for me. I tried to post a PasteBin with the full code in, but it won't let me (as I've not posted any code directly, which would be too long-winded)